# How do I retrieve all the children under a node in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do i retrieve all the information stored under the Post node. I would like to add the value to my post list which in turn will populate my recycle view. I have already tried accessing my database with the users UID but that only retrieves information for a single user.

```
My firebase structure
Post
 fyvqJOIym3RMNS7L29Oqij9HUX12 (UID)
 -LlCmqQCSmdfK9lhCjuP         (Random push key)
 desc: 
 id: 
 image: 
 name: 
 profileimage: 
 -LlCn0eTBh3dHRGek95j        (Random push key)
 desc: 
 id: 
 image: 
 name: 
 profileimage: 




/Retrieves information stored inside Post node...
    public void fetchUserInfo() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "fetch info method called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");
        postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    value = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(value);
                    randomPostKeyId = ds.getKey();
                }
                adapter = new Adapter(Shop_Activity.this, postList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("Error", databaseError.toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

So you have

```
--Post
----userUID1
------postUUID
--------postData
------postUUID
--------postData
----userUID2
------postUUID
--------postData
```

May I suggest you to structure the data this way:

```
-- Posts
---- postUUID 1
------ author: userUUID 1
------ desc: ...
------ image: ...
------ name: ...
---- postUUID 2
------ author: userUUID 1
------ desc: ...
------ image: ...
------ name: ...
---- postUUID 3
------ author: userUUID 2
------ desc: ...
------ image: ...
------ name: ...
////////////////////////////
-- Users
---- userUUID 1
------ profileimage: ...
------ ......
---- userUUID 2
------ profileimage: ...
------ ......
```

And when you want to query posts by user just query this way: `ref.child("Posts").orderByChild("author").equalsTo(userUID).add...`
and if you want all the posts just query this way:

```
ref.child("Posts").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){*/methods implementatio/*})
```

and in onChildAdded(){...} you get only single post data but this will retrieve all posts one by one and continue listening for new ones in realtime, so you just get this single post and pass it as param in a method to display this data in a desired View. Also if you want to display the user info you just query the user inside (you can create a hashmap with (String, UserClass) like (userUID, UserData) and check if you have the data for this user already and if you have it just get it instead of downloading it again and again).
But if you want to stick with this, check this out:

```
public void fetchUserInfo() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "fetch info method called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");
    postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for(DataSnapshot singlePostData : ds.getChildren() {
                    value = singlePostData.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(value);
                    randomPostKeyId = singlePostData.getKey();
                }
            }
            adapter = new Adapter(Shop_Activity.this, postList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("Error", databaseError.toString());

        }
    });
}
```

Since you obtain all the childs in Post you get objects with key userID and list with posts as value. you must iterate over each object with userID and list of posts and inside each loop to iterate over this list of posts. The code may not be very accurate but this is the logic.